# What questions should be considered to close by 3000+ users?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

As long as we don't have many hi-rep users, it is useful to have a place with list of candidates to close; at least it worked well on other betas.

Rules:

- Add a link to the candidate for closure in the top answer
- Explanation of why it needs closing is optional
- Delete it from the answer if you see that the question is closed

Comment: In fact it is just no longer relevant.

Comment: Well, we still don't have enough closevoters, even if we have high rep users. Till date I've seen maybe one question that was closed with 5 votes. The majority are closed by the ♦-binding-vote. I guess that's because there's no easy way for us non-mods to see which questions are being closevoted (is there?) Actually, I was thinking of using this in conjunction with [tag:cv-pls] in chat.. [cv-pls] was [rather controversial](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120186/close-vote-seeding-in-php-chat-getting-out-of-hand) on SO, but our community is small enough for that not to happen IMO.

Comment: Really, there should be a tab in the review section for checking out questions with closevotes.

Answer (score 2):

OK, apparently trivial answers are now automatically converted to comments by the software. So if you want to post a link here, instead of posting it as a separate answer, just add it to the following list. Once a question has been closed, edit it out.

If our chat room ever becomes more regularly active, we will move handling of close candidates there.

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/worksheets-for-khan-academy
  Off topic
- [What will be the relative speed of the fly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22256/what-will-be-the-relative-speed-of-the-fly)

  possible duplicate as linked in comments
- [What are the frameworks of physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21871/what-are-the-frameworks-of-physics)

  possibly not constructive
- [New theories and publications](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/new-theories-and-publications)

  not constructive
- [What is the origin of the naming convention for position functions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21376/2451)

  This is a language question and it may be off topic, we'll need to decide as a community.
- [Expected Energy Production From High Efficiency Solar Cells](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21702/4066)

  May be off topic