# What are the rules for closing a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720759/) was closed by three users, none a moderator. I thought (from observation) that five were needed, or a moderator? What are the rules?

Comment: We are [testing a three-vote threshold to close and reopen](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14133/44126).

Comment: dear rob, I see that **new rules** are applied since a month ago, of which I was not aware. Before asking this question I tried searching the title in meta questions and came up with nothing. Maybe there should be a clear post on **rules**  so that people can be informed and maybe think twice before asking for closure, if their vote would be so crucial. I also will think twice before voting for closure, because I was relying on the opinion of the others (btw this explains  a puzzle I had a while ago, as the question was closed when I voted closure, and I attributed this to my high reputation!